# Process list of list stored in a macro

Tags: xparse

My case is very similar to [this problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/498743/151808): I've got a list of pairs (first name, last name), and I want to process it to make last name in `\scshape`. It works fine with @egreg's solution.
But when I want to first store the list in a macro, it is not processed any more… The aim is to put the `\Bar` command in the preamble and process the list later in the document.

I've seen codes with expl3 syntax (for example [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/213130/151808), still by @egreg!), but I really don't understand it :(

Any help appreciated!

To go further is it possible to handle the case where the first name is not provided?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\Bar}[1]{\def\bar{#1}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{>{\SplitList{;}}m}{%
    \def\respdelim{\def\respdelim{, }}%
    \def\aze##1{\respdelim\fooaux{##1}}%
    \ProcessList{#1}{\aze}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooaux}{>{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{\fooauxa#1}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fooauxa}{>{\TrimSpaces}m>{\TrimSpaces}m}{\IfValueTF{#1}{\IfValueTF{#2}{#1\space{\scshape #2}}{#1}}{\IfValueTF{#2}{{\scshape#2}}}}

\begin{document}
    \foo{x,1;y;z,2}
    
    \foo{First Name1, Last Name1; First Name2, Last Name2; First Name3; ,Last Name4}
    
    \Bar{First Name1, Last Name1; First Name2, Last Name2; First Name3; ,Last Name4} % store list in \bar
    \foo{\bar} % process \bar
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bar` should be expanded once before `\foo` absorbs its argument: `\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\bar}`.

Comment: Thanks @muzimuzhiZ. That solves the main issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a different approach, defining a `\usenames` command that takes as argument a template.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\IfNotEmpty}{mm}
 {
  \tl_if_empty:nF {#1} { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\addnames}{m}
 {
  \nbur_names:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\usenames}{+m}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \__nbur_names_process:nn { #1 }
  \__nbur_names_process:
 }

\seq_new:N \g_nbur_names_seq
\seq_new:N \l__nbur_names_temp_seq
\cs_new:Nn \__nbur_names_process:nn { }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__nbur_names_process:nn { ee }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \nbur_names:n
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__nbur_names_temp_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__nbur_names_temp_seq
   {
    \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_nbur_names_seq { ##1 }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__nbur_names_process:
 {
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \g_nbur_names_seq
   {
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__nbur_names_temp_seq { , } { ##1 }
    \__nbur_names_process:ee
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__nbur_names_temp_seq { 1 } }% first name
     { \seq_item:Nn \l__nbur_names_temp_seq { 2 } }% last name
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\addnames{First Name1, Last Name1; First Name2, Last Name2; First Name3; ,Last Name4}

\usenames{\IfNotEmpty{#1}{#1 }\IfNotEmpty{#2}{\textsc{#2}}\par}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In the template, `#1` stands for the first name and `#2` for the last name.

Comment: expl3 remains weird to me… I'm going to play with this code, trying to understand it.